# Ставится ли запятая в предложении "Его уже ничего не понимающий взгляд безучастно прошел мимо домов"?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

Ставится ли запятая в таком предложении: "Его уже ничего не понимающий взгляд безучастно прошел мимо домов"?

Comment: Если отвечать на ваш вопрос буквально, то ответ: "Категорически нет". В таком предложении запятая не нужна ни по духу изложения (прочтения), ни по правилам.
А вопрос у вас возник, скорее всего, потому, что предложение построено стилистически сложно и оно неудобочитаемо.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение немного отредактировано: Его **уже ничего не понимающий** взгляд безучастно скользнул мимо домов.**

Причастный оборот не выделяется запятой в позиции перед определяемым словом. Притяжательное местоимение ***его*** неоднородно по отношению к обороту.